# Spring Data JPA .save() method is not saving in the database

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have a model :

```
public class ABC implements Serializable {
    private int baseId;
    private Integer aId;
    private Integer bId;
    private Boolean isReal;
    private TimeStamp updateTime;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "base_id", nullable = false)
    public int getBaseId() {
        return baseId;
    }
    public void setBaseId(int baseId) {
        this.baseId = baseId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getAId() {
        return aId;
    }

    public void setAId(Integer aId) {
        this.aId = aId;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
    public Integer getBId() {
        return bId;
    }

    public void setBId(Integer bId) {
        this.bId = bId;
    }
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_real")
    public Boolean getIsReal() {
        return isReal;
    }

    public void setIsReal(Boolean isReal) {
        this.isReal = isReal;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name ="update_time")
    public Timestamp getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(Timestamp updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }
}
```

I have a controller Class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "${serverconfig.api-base-path}/base")
public class BaseController {
    /**
     * Instance of an logger
     */
    private static final Logger LOG = 
        LoggerFactory.getLogger(BaseController.class);

    /**
     * Base repository
     */
    private BaseRepository baseRepository;

    /***
     *
     * @param baseRepository
     */
    public BaseController(BaseRepository baseRepository) {
        LOG.trace("BaseRepository constructor method.");
        this.baseRepository = baseRepository;
    }

    @PostMapping(path = Route.UPDATE_IS_REAL)
     // @Transactional
    public ABC updateIsReal(@Valid @RequestBody 
    @RequestParam("baseId") int baseId,

    @RequestParam("isReal") boolean isReal){
        ABC abc = baseRepository.findByBaseId(baseId);
        Date date= new Date();
        Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(date.getTime());
        abc.setBaseId(baseId);
        abc.setIsReal(isReal);
        abc.setUpdateTime(ts);

        return baseRepository.save(abc);

    }

}
```

My repository class:

```
 @Repository
 public interface BaseRepository extends 
 JpaRepository<ABC, Integer> {

    List<ABC> findByAId(Integer aId);

    ABC findByBaseId(Integer baseId);
}
```

Database table has an entry :

```
"base_id": 1,
"a_Id": 1,
"b_Id": 1,
"is_real": null,
"update_time": null
```

When I call the endpoint it gives no error and returns:

```
"base_id": 1,
"aId": 1,
"bId": 1,
"isReal": yes,
"updateTime": 018-10-01T18:30:56.765+0000
```

But When I query the database, the record is not updated there. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong. I am supplying id when I try to make a rest call and that id exists in the database.

Comment: Is your entity mapped with the `@Entity` annotation ?

Comment: yes, I have Entity annotation

Comment: There is no such "JPA save method". That is Spring Data JPA, a totally different API. FYI

Comment: I had this error because of putting @Transactional on a Junit test class, which automatically rolls back db transactions.

Answer (score 8):

With `save`, changes won't necessary be flushed to DB immediately and might stay just in memory, until flush or commit commands are issued.

With `saveAndFlush`, changes will be flushed to DB immediately.

However, if you flush the changes in transaction and do not commit them, the changes still won't be visible to the outside transactions until the commit in this transaction.

In your BaseController try changing

```
return baseRepository.save(abc);
```

to

```
return baseRepository.saveAndFlush(abc);
```

Further information [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#save-S-) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAndFlush-S-)

Comment: When I use saveAndFlush I get : no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progres

Comment: @nishakanani I think you have to use [transaction annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations), but first I think you have to refactor your code, it is not a good practice to go directly from controllers layer to repository layer without passing for a service layer

Comment: Thank you @Dazak. I agree. I added a service layer and Transaction annotation worked. I had two schemas and one schema was set as  primary schema. I was trying to refer to another schema and it was not working as I was not using Transaction annotation.

Answer (score 4):

yes, it works just replace "create" with "update"

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: I upvoted @SydMK 's answer because it was inspiring. In my case, it was something very similar. I initially had this prop set to spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update and I had Liquibase changeSets which added complexity to the DB landscape, so sometimes my save() call to JPA repository could save sometimes it couldn't and errored out with all kinds of nasty messages. Changing this prop to =create-drop gave me a cleaner slate and helped greatly to avoid this symptom.